# What is best time to call Australian immigration call center?

Tags: working-visas, immigration, australia, telephone

I wanted to get in touch with Australian immigration on +61131881 (office based in Australia Canberra) in regards to my work visa application. I called on Monday ~1pm (Australian time - AEDT +11 hours) and wait time is 1 HOUR....

I (in vain) tried looking online on what hours it's best to call them...

**Is there any resource on how busy Australian immigration call centre at what days and hours is?**

Comment: It depends on the country. I had the best results calling the visa processing centre in the US just as they opened for the morning.

Comment: @lafemmecosmique Hi, I am asking about Australian office it is based in Canberra...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably do a statistical analysis on this, working out that most calls will probably come from :

- within Australia
- India perhaps?
- China
- United Kingdom
- other large populations of immigrants

Based on this, you could look at timezones and work out that perhaps a Monday morning when it's still the weekend in Perth, India, UK, USA etc might be statistically an opportune time to call.  You could try 5 min before they open and then even if you sit in the queue on the line, at least you'd get through.